# ag-grid : How to set custom background color in column header?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid with Angular 4.
I want to be able to change the background color of individual column headers during runtime.

It seems that I have to use headerComponentFramework property in coldefs, but I have no idea how to use this.
Anybody has an idea?

regards,
Alex

Answer (score 3):

If you have a predefined set of colors for the header, I would use the `headerClass` option:

```
defaultColDef: {
  headerClass: function(params) {
    // logic to return the correct class
    return 'header-one';
  }
}
```

Then in css use the background-color property:

```
.header_one {
  background-color: red;
}
```

See the following example where clicking on a cell changes the header color:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-header-color-dynamic?file=index.js

Answer (score 1):

If using Sass then setting the `header-background-color` theme parameter should work.

The example below assumes you are using the `alpine` theme.

```css
@import "~ag-grid-community/src/styles/ag-grid.scss";
@import "~ag-grid-community/src/styles/ag-theme-alpine/sass/ag-theme-alpine-mixin";

.ag-theme-alpine {
    @include ag-theme-alpine((
        header-background-color: deeppink
    ));
}
```

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-themes-customising/#setting-parameters-using-sass

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/w8ZiwXHO7J0159rXhm9W/) that demonstrates a header component like what you want. I took it from the examples on the [docs for ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/example-angular-rich-grid/#gsc.tab=0). Take a look mostly at `header.component.html`, that's where the magic is at.

I think the only confusing part would be when you create the HeaderComponent:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements IHeaderAngularComp {
    public color: string = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
    public params: MyParams;
    private elementRef: ElementRef;

    ...

    //You will need to get the params from agInit so that you can access
    //the value for each column

    agInit(params: MyParams): void {
        this.params = params;
    }
}
```

Please check on their [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0) for more explanation, they get better every day

Comment: Looks quite good. I put this into my code. The only thing is that now the sort symbols are missing and I can't sort by clicking the column headers.

Comment: @Seeschorle Yeah, That's one downside to using the `headerComponentFramework`, you lose any default behavior that was built into the header. You will need to create an event listener that will update the sort and add the appropriate icon.

Comment: Lots of pain for just changing the bk color. I wish there was a full-featured sample headerComponent available, which can be modified. In the case of just changing color I would even prefer to just have an attribute for that. I guess it isn't too uncommon thing to change color.